# use dynamically scaled image width for left positioning of the other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

i have a dynamically scaled image (fixed position, windowheight) so it scales proportionally and changes its width. I would like to use its width to set the left positioning of an another div. Can I use something like this?

```
$("#menubar img").ready(function() {
     var bodywidth = $("#menubar img").width();
        $("#text").left(bodywidth);
});

$("#menubar img").resize(function() {
   var bodywidth = $("#menubar img").width();
        $("#text").left(bodywidth);
});
```

I am lost in the script :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var bodywidth = $("#menubar img").width();` will give you a number, such as 120. Note that this is in pixels but lacks units. Setting anything to the result of this value is meaningless.

You need:

```
 $("#text").css('left',bodywidth+'px');
```

This assumes that "the other div" is using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menubar img").ready(function() {
 var bodywidth = $("#menubar img").width();
    $("#text").css('left',bodywidth.toString().concat('px'));});$("#menubar img").resize(function() {   var bodywidth = $("#menubar img").width();        $("#text").css('left',bodywidth.toString().concat('px'));});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot for quick help. But I tried that with no success... :(

Comment: srry, it works in IE and FF but not in chrome... is there any chrome friendly way?